# Take an id form the user and check if that employee with given employee id is existing or not, if it exists show Employee information

Tags: java

Take an id form the user and check if that employee with given employee id is existing or not, if it exists show Employee information .

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 

import java.util.Iterator;

import java.util.Scanner;
```

// i am trying to display the perticular employee details  but am unable to display anything
// is there any way i can do that

```
class Employee{

    int empid;
    String name;
    float basicSal;
    public Employee(int empid, String name, float basicSal) {
        super();
        this.empid = empid;
        this.name = name;
        this.basicSal = basicSal;
    }
    public void setEmpid(int empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public float getBasicSal() {
        return basicSal;
    }
    public void setBasicSal(float basicSal) {
        this.basicSal = basicSal;
    }
    
}
public class EmployeeExecuter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Employee> empl = new ArrayList<>(5);
        Employee ob2 = new Employee(2,"bat",3000);
        Employee ob3 = new Employee(3,"cat",4000);
        Employee ob4 = new Employee(4,"dog",5000);
        Employee ob5 = new Employee(5,"rat",6000);
        empl.add(ob1);
        empl.add(ob2);
        empl.add(ob3);
        empl.add(ob4);
        empl.add(ob5);
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter empid :");
        int id = sc.nextInt();
    

        if(empl.contains(id)) {
        Iterator<Employee> sit = empl.iterator();
        while(sit.hasNext()) {
            Employee emps= sit.next();
            System.out.println(emps.getEmpid()+ " " +emps.getName()+ " " +emps.getBasicSal());
       
         }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: `empl.contains(id)` always return false b/c `id` is not an Employee object.

Answer (score 0):

`empl.contains(id)` always return false b/c id is not an Employee object.

How to fix:

Change `if(empl.contains(id))`
into

```
for (Employee e : empl) {
   if(e.getEmpid() == id) {
       System.out.println(emps.getEmpid()+ " " +emps.getName()+ " " +emps.getBasicSal());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much It Worked But instead emps i changed to e then it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(Employee emp:empl){

if(emp.getEmpid()==id){
     System.out.println(emp.getEmpid()+ " " +emp.getName()+ " " +emp.getBasicSal());
     break;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a student assignment. How do you solve this problem as a person?

Assume you have a sheet of paper with employee information listed on it this list of employees is not sorted.  Each line on the sheet contains the info for a single employee.  The natural approach is to check each record from the top of the list to the bottom and check for the given ID.

It works the same for a program.  You iterate through the list looking for the ID.

In pseudocode...

```
function findEmploye (List employees, ID id)
  for each Employee E in List of Employee
    if E.id = ID then return E
  end-for
  return null
end-function
```

In Java, using for-each loop...

```
public Employee findEmployee(List<Employee> employees, int id) {
  for (Employee e : employees) {
    if (e.getId() == id) {
      return e;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

In Java, using the Stream API...

```
public Employee findEmployee(List<Employee> employees, int id) {
  return employees.filter(e -> e.getId() == id).findAny().get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

doesnt have a getters of the employeeID

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EmployeeExecuter {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Employee> empl = new ArrayList<>(5);
    Employee ob2 = new Employee(2,"bat",3000);
    Employee ob3 = new Employee(3,"cat",4000);
    Employee ob4 = new Employee(4,"dog",5000);
    Employee ob5 = new Employee(5,"rat",6000);
    empl.add(ob1);
    empl.add(ob2);
    empl.add(ob3);
    empl.add(ob4);
    empl.add(ob5);
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter empid :");
    int id = sc.nextInt();

    empl.filter(e -> e.getId() == id).findAny().get().forEach(System.out::println);
   } }
```

> easy and fast way